# Rainbow cursor every time on safari

Tags: macos, safari, apple-silicon

I have a new MacBook Air M1 and whenever I enter password in webpage in safari browser a rainbow cursor appears and safari gets stuck ,but the remaining   apps work perfectly fine, but the safari gets struck for about 10-15 seconds and I can't do anything in safari expect force quit for that period.  Is this normal with safari ?

Comment: you are asking whether this is normal, the answer is no, but you most likely want advice on how to resolve this issue. Asking clear, precise, concise and logical questions is really important. So, tell us what you have done in order  to resolve this issue except force quitting safari. Reboot? Reset NVRAM/PRAM and SMC? Use a different browser? What webpage specifically has problems, or all websites that ask for a password? Do you use a keychain tool like iCloud Keychain or are you manually typing in the password? Please read the Tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

The rainbow cursor indicates that the application in question is blocked because the system watches for it saying it’s ready for things like keyboard input.

The page you are visiting is causing an entire app to block so that’s a problem for sure if you need that page to work before it gets fixed. It’s normal and expected the system lets you know one app is blocked, so you can go do other tasks in other apps and eventually force Safari to quit when you tire of waiting for it.